# $|G| = ?$ if its subgroups are $\{e\}$, $G$ itself, and a subgroup of order $7$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Suppose that a cyclic group $G$ has exactly three subgroups: $G$ itself, $\{ e \}$, and a subgroup of order $7$.  What is $|G|$?  What can you say if $7$ is replaced with $p$ where $p$ is prime?

I know that $7$ is a divisor of $|G|$ here, but I can't figure anything else past that.

Comment: Are there any other divisors of $|G|$? Or should I say "*Can* there be any other divisors?" (Hint: Sylow Theorems, or, for a more elementary version, Cauchy's Theorem.)

Comment: @JohnHughes For cyclic groups, Sylow and Cauchy are not even needed.

Comment: Agreed ... I missed the word "cyclic" in my too-quick reading. :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Recall that subgroups of a finite cyclic group $G$ are in one-to-one correspondence with divisors of $|G|$.

So, you need a number $n$, with its only divisors being $1$,$7$ and $n$. Obviously $n=49$, and $G=C_{49}$ - the cyclic group of order $49$.

Answer (score 4):

A finite cyclic group has a subgroup of order $d$ for every divisor $d$ of $|G|$. So we are told that $|G|$ has exactly three divisors, $1$, $p$, and $|G|$.
This implies $|G|=p^2$. (In fact, we immediately see that $|G|$ must be a perfect square because all non-squares have an *even* nmumber of divisors).